# How to center the image inside of canvas in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a problem with centring the image inside of the canvas. Canvas has to be full sized. The whole thing should create a web preloader. Styling image inside of css does not work in this case.

```
<style> canvas{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 99;   }

</style>   <body>
    <canvas id="c"><img id="logo" width="800" height="150" src="imgsource" alt="logo"></canvas> <div>   web content </div>

    <script>

    jQuery(window).on('load', function() { 
    jQuery('#c').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow'); 
    jQuery('body').delay(7000).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    })


    window.onload = function() {
        var c = document.getElementById("c");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("logo");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 0);


    } </script>
```

Comment: set the width and height attributes on the canvas

Comment: When I am setting the width and height of attributes on the canvas the image disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The following only demonstrates the centering of an image inside a canvas with `drawImg`. Note that the image to the left is from the html `<img>` element while the other is from the `drawImg` call.

Outside of stackoverflow you'd have to wait for the image to load before drawing it, but as you also already use `.on('load', ...)` i assume you are aware of that.

To avoid having two images, create the [image element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) in javascript and don't add it to the document but only use it for rendering.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let img = document.getElementById("i");

//just to make the area the canvas occupies visible
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

//draw the image centered
ctx.drawImage(
  img,
  canvas.width / 2 - img.width / 2,
  canvas.height / 2 - img.height / 2
);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img id="i" src="http://i.imgur.com/kdJicdy.png"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240">Your browser doesn't support canvas</canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'http://placehold.it/300x550';
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var wrh = image.width / image.height;
        var newWidth = canvas.width;
        var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
        if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
                    newHeight = canvas.height;
            newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
        }
        var xOffset = newWidth < canvas.width ? ((canvas.width - newWidth) / 2) : 0;
        var yOffset = newHeight < canvas.height ? ((canvas.height - newHeight) / 2) : 0;

        canvasContext.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, newWidth, newHeight);
      };
```

```
   <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black" />
```